# Where can I get a refund on unicorn coins?

Tags: support, april-fools, unicoins

I have purchased the Guaranteed Answer power and selected that I wish the answers to be helpful.

They are not.

I feel I have been misled and cheated out of my hard earned coins!

Where can I request a refund?

Comment: Satisfaction guaranteed? Not satisfied?  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_v._Chung

Answer (score 10):

You can spend another 10 unicorns to remove the helpful answers, if you wish.

Answer (score -1):

You have to spend another **50 Unicorns** to actually use the power pack. Hence you are **fooled** by Stack on ***April Fool's Day***.

OR

You can remove the power pack by **compromising** 10 Unicorns and get remaining back.